# Unit Test with InMemory Database gives "Unable to track an instance of type 'VwCustomerUser' because it does not have a primary key"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I am trying to use In memory database unit testing to test my Entity Framework DbContext class as per https://www.thecodebuzz.com/dbcontext-mock-and-unit-test-entity-framework-net-core/comment-page-1/?unapproved=3553&moderation-hash=befd47d3c1cab4bc7716b080618b2a0b#comment-3553

I am able to generate a DbContext in memory for my entities and test my code. However, one of my entities comes from a view, and does not have a primary key. When I populate my DbContext like, e.g.,

```
    context.MyView.Add(new MyView { 
        Country = “USA”, 
        State = “NY”, 
        Address = “Test1”, 
        ZipCode = “121312” 
     });
```

I get the error: “Unable to track an instance of type ‘MyView’ because it does not have a primary key. Only entity types with primary keys may be tracked.”.

Could anybody please advise? Thank you so much.

Ray

Comment: You should be able to define a composite key in EF to keep it happy. If you aren't employing EF Code First to manage the schema, EF's defined keys are just there to help it uniquely identify rows and do not actually need to be backed up by Keys in the underlying data source. They just need to resolve down to a unique row. If the data can be duplicated then you may be able to satisfy EF by ensuring you only request the data `AsNoTracking()` or disable tracking in the DbContext.

Comment: Yes!!! Thanks Steve. that made the trick.

Comment: @Ramon What exactly did the trick? Because I am facing the same issue now, and can't seem to find a way around it.